# How to convert value from getAmplitude() to it's corresponding RMS voltage value (mV)

Tags: android, audio, microphone, amplitude

I am writing an android app in which I want to convert the signal amplitude coming from microphone to its corresponding rms voltage.

I know we can use `getMaxAmplitude()`. But I don't know how to convert the value that we get from `getMaxAmplitude()` to a RMS voltage.

I researched a lot but didn't find anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Generally the device will supply voltage to the microphone.**

First, to answer your question: I believe you won't find a way to get the magnitude of this voltage from the Android API. If you will find anything it will beon the NDK side of things, deep in the driver somewhere, hence the each device will be different.

I will presume you're using a device that expects an [electret microphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret_microphone) as I am sure you know, this is how it generally works:

Each device will supply slightly different voltage, so you will probably have to measure it. I have seen **2.5V**,  **3.2V** or **4V**, sometimes those values are adjustable from the softwareside in drivers, but again each device will work differently.

These things are not really designed to be run as scopes, but it is doable, especially if you only target one specific device.

*Sorry for the bad news and good luck with your project  ;)*

Comment: I basically want to convert the getmaxamplitude() data that usually is in dB to voltage. So lets for instance, the level of the signal is -100dB that might correspong to the maybe 50mV . So I need a formula that converts the db values into volts..

Comment: Converting just from dB to Voltage is impossible. dB are a ratio. What you can do is convert that to a Volt ratio (V/Vd = 10^(dB/20) ) but to calculate the Voltage you still need to know the other Voltage!